# Storing function call and arguments in a config file to let a php script know what to do

Tags: php, xml, config

is there a way to represent function calls in a config file (e.g. XML) ?
I am trying to create a config file which tells my php script what functions to call (and with which arguments) if the user requested info about a specific service. Currently these information are stored ~50 different php files (which luckily have a pattern...) and I filter them out of it by searching for the calls and then retrieving the arguments. As you can guess this is error prone and rigid, so I want to change this asap.
I know that I can evaluate a string in php and have it executed. While my script and config file will be on the same server (and probably maintained by the same person) this still seems insecure to me. This would be my last resort.

If I do it in an xml file I would like to use the xml tags as a description since the calls may change. E.g.

```
<Service name="Foo" active="1" ID="12">
  <DescriptiveName>
    <Call1>getSomeValueFromAServer(String aServer)</Call1>
    <Call2>getAnotherValueFromAnotherServer(String[] aWholeBunchOfServers)</Call2>
  </DescriptiveName>
  <SomethingElseINeedToKnow>
     <Call1>getValue(some params)</Call1>
     <Call2>getValue(some params)</Call2>
  </SomethingElseINeedToKnow>
</Service>
```

As you can see the argument may also be an array in some cases.
A descriptive Name would allow me to always reference that tag. That way I would not have to change my php if something in the config changes. 
I want to get it done in a way that my program can just "iterate" over everything. So that I don´t need to change anything if a new descriptive tag is added (maybe by giving them some id that increments?).

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to look at how Symfony structures its service container in XML, particularly around setter injection calls: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/calls.html (the XML tab). I'd definitely avoid storing the function name and the arguments as a single string though, that road leads to `eval()`, and that's not where you want to go.

Comment: @iainn Thanks for the hint. I will take a look at it.

Comment: @iainn How would I then use a config like that without using eval (or installing symfony)?